# Maximum Likelihood estimators in reation to linear models

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, inference, estimators

Consider two simple linear models.

$y_{1j}=\alpha _1+\beta_{1}x_{1j}+\epsilon_{1j}$ and
$y_{2j}=\alpha _2+\beta_{2}x_{2j}+\epsilon_{2j}$  , $ j=1,2,...,n>2$ where $ \epsilon_{ij}$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$
I have two questions.

1 ) Show that the point on the x-axis where the two lines intersect is given by $x_0$=${\alpha_1-\alpha_2}\over \beta_2-\beta_1$
2)Obtain the maximum likelihood estimators of $\sigma^2$ and $x_0$

For question 1) what I did was,
Supposing at $x_0,y_0$ the two lines intersect I substituted $x_0,y_0$  to the two equations.But then what happens to the error terms.Can I suppose that the errors in estimating  $x_0,y_0$ from both equations are the same?

For 2)

$y_{ij}$ has a Normal distribution.
I calculated $E(y_{1,j})$   and $E(y_{2,j})$ separately.Can I say that $E(X_{1j})$ =$E(X_{2j})$
and  $E(y_{1,j})$ = $E(y_{2,j})$.
  Thereby I obtained $E(y_{ij})$=${\beta_2\alpha_1-\beta_1\alpha_2}\over\beta_2-\beta_1$

Similarly $V(y_{ij})=\sigma^2$

Then joint probability density function for $y_{ij}$ is $\prod_{i=1}^2\prod_{j=1}^n $$1\over\sqrt {2\pi\sigma^2}$$
e^{{-(y_{ij}-\mu})^2} / 2\sigma^2$ where $\mu=$${\beta_2\alpha_1-\beta_1\alpha_2}\over\beta_2-\beta_1$   .Is this a correct joint p.d.f for y?

Does $x_0$ also has a normal distribution.Is **$V(x_0)=0$**.I don't understand how to obtain **MLE for $x_0$** .

Can someone please help me to do this please

Comment: Some issues that it appears need clarification/clean up: 1) are the two error terms independent? 2) Either the $X$'s are treated as deterministic (so they cannot have an expected value, or a distribution), or they are stochastic, in which case you can say that the $Y$'s have a normal distribution only conditionally on the $X$'s. 3) The expression for $x_0$ should have in the right-hand-side the _estimated_ parameters, not their true unknown values (you would not have "lines" other wise -they are obviously the fitted lines here). CONT'D

Comment: CONT'D... 4) Taking into account 3) in the previous comment, the point where the two lines cross is a point where $\hat y_{1i} = \hat y_{2i}=\hat y_0$ and $x_{1i} = x_{2i}=x_0$.

Comment: Yes errors are independent.It says that errors are independent and identically distributed .I missed that in the post.What you mean by "The expression for x0 should have in the right-hand-side the estimated parameters" is that the alpha's and beta's in$ x_0$ should be $\hat\alpha$,$\hat\beta$

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos : Finding MLE part is where I have no idea.Can you please give me any help in order to do that part

Comment: Hint:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/543277/meaning-of-invariance-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator